# How to do regex Parsing by tags

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, event-log

I have a homework to do parsing for event log message. The main purpose of the homework is to mention the values by tag1, tag2 ,....etc. 
Kindly, could you please help me to parse the below message:

```html
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
<System><Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' Guid='{xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx}'/>
<EventID>4688</EventID>
<Version>2</Version>
<Level>Information</Level>
<Task>Process Creation</Task>
<Opcode>Info</Opcode>
<Keywords>Audit Success</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime='2018-03-11T19:39:26.279779254Z'/>
<EventRecordID>155726</EventRecordID>
<Correlation/><Execution ProcessID='4' ThreadID='20072'/>
<Channel>Security</Channel>
<Computer>COMPUTER.DOMAIN.COM</Computer>
<Security/></System>
<EventData>A new process has been created.

Creator Subject:
 Security ID:  DOMAIN\USER
 Account Name:  USER
 Account Domain:  DOMAIN
 Logon ID:  XxXXXXXX

Target Subject:
 Security ID:  NULL SID
 Account Name:  -
 Account Domain:  -
 Logon ID:  0x0

Process Information:
 New Process ID:  0xXXXX
 New Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 Token Elevation Type: %%8547
 Mandatory Label:  Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level
 Creator Process ID: 0x00a1
 Creator Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
 Process Command Line: wmic  computersystem get computername
```

The idea is that to insert a tag for each result as the below:

```html
<EventID>(?<tag1>\d+)</EventID><Version>(?<tag2>\d+)</Version><Level>(?<tag3>.*?)</Level>.*?<Execution ProcessID='(?<tag4>.*?)'.*?/>.*<Computer>(?<tag5>.*?)</Computer>
```

Thanks and Regard.

Comment: Does it have to be by regex?

Comment: Dear Lieven, thanks for your comment. and about the parsing yes it does, and I have to do it by regex.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/br2h9B/1